# How do I save the scraped data from Nokogiri to a Rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I want to save the scraped data to the database so that I can implement search and sorting functionality on it.

I tried creating a new Rake task and updating attributes but for that I need to run `rake fetch-data` every time the data is scraped.

app/controller

```
def show
  url = @scrapper.url 
  data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  @doc= data.css(".s-item-container")
end
```

app/views/show

```
 <% @doc.each do |item| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= item.css(".s-access-title").text %></td>
     <td><%= item.css(".s-price").text %></td>
     <td><%= item.css("span+ .a-text-normal").text %></td>
   </tr>
 <% end %>
```

[The data I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB0BP.png)

It didnt work. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Need to know how the crawler is running now in your system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a database `rake db:create`
2. Create 'Product' model `rails g model Product title:string price:decimal rating:float`
3. Create a rake task. Parse data and save it in the database.

> ```
> doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@scrapper.url ))
> items = doc.css(".s-item-container")
> items.each do |item|
>   Product.create!(
>       title: item.css(".s-access-title").text.strip,
>       price: item.css(".s-price").text.to_d,
>       rating: item.css("span+ .a-text-normal").text.to_f)
> end
> ```

to prevent duplicates

```
items.each do |item|
    title = item.css(".s-access-title").text.strip
    product = Product.find_or_initialize(title: title)
    product.price = item.css(".s-price").text.to_d
    product.rating = item.css("span+ .a-text-normal").text.to_f
    product.save!
  end
```

4. Get data from Product model in your controller and show it in the view

Comment: Don't use `item.css(".s-access-title").text` unless you're absolutely sure it's going to return usable data. Usually it concatenates all the text in all the found elements resulting in run-on strings that are impossible to untangle or split. `css(...).map(&:text)` is usually what you want to do.